# How can I combine row values into a new row in pandas

Tags: pandas

[I would like to merge multiple rows with different names into a new row.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRW4d.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df.set_index('Cities',inplace=True)
df.loc['A']=df.loc['A']+df.loc['B']
df=df.drop('B').rename(index={'A':'A/B'}).reset_index()
```

`set_index('Cities')` sets `Cities` as an index to add using `loc`. Then `A` is renamed `A / B` and cities are reset as a column using `reset_index`

**note:** if Cities was the index you don need:

`df.set_index('Cities',inplace=True)`

Comment: It worked perfect, thank you.

Comment: Accept my answer!